# What's the best way to add a bunch of Button to a ScrollPane?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, scrollpane

I'm kinda new to JavaFx, for my application I need to set an indeterminate bunch of buttons on a part of the screen. Since I don't know how many buttons I'll need until the program is started, I thought on set a **ScrollPane** to this part of the screen, and there add dynamically a bunch of **HBox** containing the buttons (I use a **List<>** of buttons and a **List<>** of **HBox**, so I can create a new **HBox** for each 8 buttons).

The idea is use the **ScrollPane** to scroll between the different **HBox** which contains the buttons, so I don't need to always show all buttons. The problem is that it seems that you can't add directly a bunch of **HBox** to a **ScrollPane**. Is there anyway to perform this?? My code will be something like this:

```
public void startApp(int nDetect){   
    this.primaryStage = new Stage();
    this.nDetect = nDetect;
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();

    Group root = new Group();
    .
    .
    .
    LinkedList<Button> buttons = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<HBox> boxes = new LinkedList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<this.nDetect; i++) {
        if(i%8 == 0){
            boxes.add(new HBox());
            boxes.get(i/8).setSpacing(5);
        }
        boxes.get(i/8).getChildren().add(buttons.get(i)) //add the button to the appropriate HBox
    }

    ScrollPane spane = new ScrollPane();

    for( HBox h : boxes){
        //add every element in "boxes" to the ScrollPane
    }
    bp.setTop(spane);
    root.getChildren().add(bp);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want your buttons laid out within a grid within a scroll pane.

The appropriate layout for that would be a [`GridPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html).

[image: button grid]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonLinesInScrollPane extends Application {

    private static final double BUTTONS_PER_LINE = 8;
    private static final double NUM_BUTTON_LINES = 8;
    private static final double BUTTON_PADDING   = 5;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(BUTTON_PADDING));
        grid.setHgap(BUTTON_PADDING);
        grid.setVgap(BUTTON_PADDING);

        for (int r = 0; r < NUM_BUTTON_LINES; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < BUTTONS_PER_LINE; c++) {
                Button button = new Button(r + ":" + c);
                grid.add(button, c, r);
            }
        }

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(grid);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was as easy as that

Answer (score 2):

A `ScrollPane` wraps another `Node`. Just make a single `HBox` (or `VBox`), set that as content of the scroll pane and add all `Button`s to the box. The box will scale automatically and the scroll pane will stay the same size but automatically draw horizontal and/or vertical sliders as the content grows beyond its bounds.

Comment: The problem is that I want to organize buttons in lines of 8 (there'll always be at least a line of 8 visible buttons, and you have to scroll down to see the next line of 8). Adding every button to an HBox and this to the ScrollPane, it shows a single line with horizontal scroll

Comment: Then you should use a `GridPane`, as suggested by @jewelsea